# Evince, mouse wheel does not change pages (page up/page down behaviour)

Tags: evince, scrolling

My mouse wheel behaves very well only within evince I have the following trouble. When switching into uncontinous view mode, I cannot switch to previous page (mouse up) nor to next page (mouse down). I use ubuntu 11.10 with evince 3.2.1-0ubuntu2 from offical repos.

I though this was not implemented, now the funny thing is, on my laptop also running 11.10 this works! So where should I look in order to restore desired behaviour?

Comment: Are you unable to scroll between pages in non-continuous mode? In continuous mode, the mouse scroll goes in one-page increments. In non-continuous it will go one line at a time, from page to page. Are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: Exactly! I see different behaviour. On the laptop the things work as you described: In non-continous mode, the pages change while using mouse scroll, while the same does not work on my workstation. I guess I should look compare evince configurations with dconf-editor as well as with gconf-editor.

Comment: I've compared them, but they look exactly the same. In both tools.

Comment: And now, that is strange: In both the default is set to non-continous view mode (has nothing to do with my original problem) And on the laptop this default is working, but on the workstation not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I was a bit heedless, it works when I disable continuous mode and viewing with "best-fit" zoom level. (It works only within the best-fit mode, when switching to 50% or something similar it does not work).

To change modes click the box displaying the zoom percentage.

Comment: Just to make that clear, I just tried it out: Scroll wheel page flip works ONLY in "fit page" mode.
It does NOT work in any other mode ("fit width", %), even if that mode amounts to the same zoom %! What the hell...

Comment: It's 2014 and the behaviour is exactly the same that Jakob mentions. This is absurd.

Comment: 2019 and the same

Answer (score 2):

go to the hamburger menu on the top right - there is an option "continuous" there. That should fix it!

Comment: You may have accidentally deselected this option by typing "c". Just happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a weird interaction between "scroll continuously" and "zoom" here.  If you have "scroll continuously" off, then the action of the mouse-scroll wheel (or arrow keys) depends on the zoom level.

If zoom level is "fit page" or lower (in %), then you can scroll through pages.  If zoom level is above that (even though it may look like the page fits onto the screen fine), the mouse-wheel scrolls only *within* a page, and the only way to get to other pages seems to be to enter the page number in the text box at top right.  Although the behavior makes some sense, it's frustrating if you don't know it and cannot seem to navigate to any other page.